# Return a class object back to Aura component and iterate over the values in the list and display on in the UI

Tags: visualforce, lightning-aura-components

I want to return a an objct/class to javascript handler and iterate through elements and display them on a page in `<di>` or something. But I seem not to be able to retrieve the `List<PointsToExpire>` in my javascript handler.

This is my apex class

```
public with sharing class PersonAccountLoyaltyController {
    @AuraEnabled public static Utilities_Custom_Settings__c getUtilityCustomSettings(){
        return Utilities_Custom_Settings__c.getInstance();
    }
    
    @AuraEnabled
    public static List<PointsToExpire> callLoyaltyInformation(String accountId) {
        postToChatter(accountId); //Log that the user opened the account
        return GetLoyaltyInformation(accountId); 
    }

    private class PointsToExpire {
        string amount {get; set;}
        string dateExpired {get; set;}
    }
    
    public static List<PointsToExpire> GetLoyaltyInformation(String accountId) {
        System.debug('---GetLoyaltyInformation---');

        List<PointsToExpire> pointsToExpire = new List<PointsToExpire>();
        PointsToExpire pte1 = new PointsToExpire();
        pte1.amount = '150000';
        pte1.dateExpired = '2024-12-31';
        PointsToExpire pte2 = new PointsToExpire();
        pte2.amount = '160000';
        pte2.dateExpired = '2024-10-31';
        LoyaltyResult lr = new LoyaltyResult();
        pointsToExpire.add(pte1);
        pointsToExpire.add(pte2);

        System.debug(pointsToExpire);
        return pointsToExpire;
    }
}
```

Here is a snippet from the aura component

```
<aura:component controller="PersonAccountLoyaltyController" implements="flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId" access="global" >
    <aura:attribute name="recordId" type="String"/>
    <aura:attribute name="record" type="Object"/>
    <aura:attribute name="record2" type="List"/>
    <aura:attribute name="simpleRecord" type="Object"/>
    <aura:attribute name="recordError" type="String"/>
    <aura:attribute name="showComponent" type="boolean" default="false"/>
    <aura:attribute name="error" type="String"/>
    <aura:attribute name="lcpUrl" type="String"/>
    new aura atribue obj. depPoints
    <lightning:workspaceAPI aura:id="workspace" />
    
    
    <force:recordData aura:id="record"
    fields="MyOrgID__c,LoyaltyStatus__c,CardPoints__c,ClubPoints__c,"
    recordId="{!v.recordId}"
    targetError="{!v.recordError}"
    targetRecord="{!v.record}"
    targetFields ="{!v.simpleRecord}"
    mode="VIEW"
    recordUpdated="{!c.doInit}"/>
 <aura:renderIf isTrue="{!v.showComponent == true}">
```

and the javascript controller

```
({
    doInit : function(component, event, helper) {
        // create a one-time use instance of the serverEcho action
            // in the server-side controller
            console.log("---doInit->PersonAcccountLoyaltyController---");
            var action = component.get("c.callLoyaltyInformation");
            console.log(component.get("v.simpleRecord"));
            action.setParams({ "accountId" : component.get("v.recordId") });
            action.setBackground();
            // Create a callback that is executed after 
            // the server-side action returns
            action.setCallback(this, function(response) {
                var state = response.getState();
                if (state === "SUCCESS") {
                    console.log('Successful callout Loyalty');
                    //get link before displaying
                    helper.getCustomSettings(component);
                    // component.set(return) values
                    //component.set("v.record", response.getReturnValue());
                    component.set("v.record2", response.getReturnValue());
                }
                else if (state === "ERROR") {
                    component.set("v.error", "Be aware that this information might not be up to date. There was an issue in aquiring the newest information. Try refreshing the page.")
                    component.set("v.showComponent", true);
                }
            });
            $A.enqueueAction(action);
    },
})
```

and javascript helper

```
({
    getCustomSettings : function(component) {
        var action = component.get("c.getUtilityCustomSettings");
        action.setCallback(this, function(response) {
            if(component.isValid() && response !== null && response.getState() == 'SUCCESS'){
                var url = response.getReturnValue().LCP_URL__c;
                component.set("v.lcpUrl", url);
                //display component
                component.set("v.showComponent", true);
            }
        });
        $A.enqueueAction(action);
    }
})
```

Comment: why are you not setting "showComponent" attribute to true when you get the response as success

Comment: @User6670 I've edit the question, added javascript helper, I think what your are asking about it there!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need @AuraEnabled annotation to enables client- and server-side access to an Apex controller method and properties.

```
public class PointsToExpire {
    @AuraEnabled
    public string amount {get; set;}
    @AuraEnabled
    public string dateExpired {get; set;}
}
```

and for iteration on the front-end, you can do the following.

```
<aura:iteration items="{!v.records}" var="pteObj">
    <div>
        <strong>Amount : </strong> {!pteObj.amount}<br/>
        <strong>Date Expired : </strong> {!pteObj.dateExpired}
    </div>
</aura:iteration>
```

Comment: yes you need to make your inner class and properties as public as shown in above code.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use an inner class as a return value / attribute in `Aura`.

Here:

> Custom classes used for component attributes shouldn’t be inner classes or use inheritance. While these Apex language features might work in some situations, there are known issues, and their use is unsupported in all cases.

Link [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/ref_attr_types_apex.htm)

**HOWEVER** You do have options. You can either make the class a full outer class or you can get sneaky and make the inner class implement an interface - which you can use as the attribute.

Inside the main `PersonAccountLoyaltyController` `Apex` class:

```
public interface PointsToExpireType {}
public class PointsToExpire implemements PointsToExpireType  {
    string amount {get; set;}
    string dateExpired {get; set;}
}
```

You of course would return a `List<PointsToExpireType>` to `Aura`.

Your attribute would be like:

```
<aura:attribute name="pointsToExpire" type="List"/>
<!-- or -->
<aura:attribute name="pointsToExpireV2" type="PointsToExpireType[]" default="[]"/>
```

I think that's all you need to do.